# Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem: Clarification

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of complex measurable functions such that $$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$$ exists for every $x\in X$. If there is a function $g\in L(\mu)$ such that $$|f_{n}(x)|\leq g(x)$$ then $f\in L(\mu)$ $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_X |f-f_n|d\mu=0$$ and $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_X f_nd\mu=\int_X f d\mu$$

My problem lies in understanding what $|f_{n}(x)|\leq g(x)$ means given that it wasn't specified that $\operatorname{Im}(g)=0$. Is it assumed that $g$ is always real valued?

Comment: The absolute value of a complex function $f$ is always real isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It even assumes that $g$ is $\mu$-a.e. non-negative!

Comment: @SangchulLee But what does it mean to say a complex number is greater than a real number without specifying the order?

Comment: $g$ is real valued.

Comment: You know, many analysts are such lazy people that they can use $g\geq 0$ simply to mean '$g$ is real-valued and non-negative'. Perhaps you can be a generous person and correct whatever is written informally by yourself.

Comment: @SangchulLee This is the first time I had seen this done(reference a larger class only to implicitly restrict that class) and in the original question I did ask if it was a real function. Clarity is the hallmark of communication, up to this point the book had pretty good at clarifying things that may lead to obvious confusion. So for me to assume that the author not writing that $g$  is real valued simply because he is lazy, and not because he needed the full blunt power of a complex function and not simply a real valued function or   just writing $$|f|\leq\operatorname{Re}(g)$$ seem silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy and common to identify $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$; however, for this inequality, this identification is leading you astray. Instead, realize that $\Omega \ni x \mapsto |f(x)|$ is a function $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, and hence the comparison $|f(x)| \leq g(x)$ is (implicitly) comparing two functions $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is there some standard order on the complex numbers that makes them an ordered field? Otherwise how would $|f(x)|\leq g(x)$ makes sense when $|f(x)|=y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=a+ib\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

Just pretend it said, "If there is a real-valued function $g \in L(\mu)$..."  The author probably thinks it goes without saying that $g$ is real-valued, because otherwise the statement $|f_n(x) | \leq g(x)$ would not make sense.